# iPad pro not showing full screen content in react native (xcode 14.0.1)

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, ipad

When I run app on ios mobile simulator it works perfectly. But the problem is when i run app on iPad pro the content didn't show properly it seems like mobile ui. There are space areas in the left and Righ sides. I didn't get the actual problem.

> Xcode version-`14.0.1` and iPad version-- `iPad pro 5 generations (12.9 inch display)`.

code example:

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Please Check the attached file, And suggest to me to solve this issue that how can make full screen in react native!

[image]

Note: I try to solve it by changing the `Targeted Device Families` to `iPhone, iPad` because there is no `universal` option in mentioned Xcode given in the attached file.
[image]

Comment: You have created an iPhones only app. You need to change the Xcode project to be universal.

Comment: hello @Paulw11, thanks for your response. I already updated the questions because there is no universal option. Please check it again.

Comment: Yes, you need to target iPhone and iPad and ensure you include a launch storyboard that supports both iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issues in **Xcode version**: `14.0.1`, follow the below instructions as given,

1. Make sure selected `iPhone, iPad` from ***Build Settings / Targeted Device Families*** of Xcode as given attached file,
   [image: Targeted Device Families]
2. In ***Supported Destination***, need to add both `iPhone` and `iPad` as given in the attached file,
   [image: Supported Destination]
3. Delete the previous app from the simulator
4. Delete all of the files from `...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
5. Then ***Clean the  Build Folder*** from Xcode(`Product->Clean Build Folder`)

Then Run the app using mentioned commands,

- Start Metro: `npm start`
- Run the App: `npx react-native run-ios`

And All is Done!!!